# Alter Polymer template binding at runtime

Tags: polymer

I'm working on a way to bind the Light DOM contents of an element into the Shadows. You can see the WIP at:

https://ele.io/mbleigh/contents-template

What I'm wondering here is how to support something akin to the `bind` attribute on templates. Is it possible to alter the binding of a template after it's been attached to the DOM? I know you can manually set `node.model` but I'd like to be able to use Polymer's text binding syntax so that the element could be something like:

```
<contents-template bind="{{data as user}}"></contents-template>
```

Or something like that. Anything that would allow me to basically "pass through" that bidning on the external element to an internal template would be helpful.